# Limited Windows users can't login in SQL based app after SQL Server migration

Tags: sql-server, windows, authentication

Just moved a SQL Server 2012 (yeah I know it's old) instance to a new server. If we login to a Windows 10 workstation as an admin user, we can launch our SQL Server based app and login with our SQL Server user.

If we login to the same workstation with a limited Windows user and try to launch the SQL Server app with the exact same SQL Server user the Windows admin user used we get this error:

> An unknown logon error occurred

We know the login is good as it works with the Windows Admin user.  Our Active Directory is housed on a different server than SQL Server.

We really haven't done much of anything. After the migration one of our admin users logged into their workstation and their login worked.  Then we had a normal user try the same thing and we got this error

> An unknown logon error occurred

We then had the admin user use the normal Windows user's SQL Server login and it worked. We tried updating the password for the SQL Server user we were testing with and that made no difference. The Windows Admin user can still login to the SQL Server App but the normal or limited Windows user cannot login to the SQL Server App. We're at a loss as to why it works with a Windows Admin user but not a limited Windows user.

Has anyone else ever encountered this?

Thank you,

Comment: Did you migrate any of the server-level logins to the new server? AD users can only connect if given permission to, and normally this is done by giving an AD Group permission to connect to SQL Server. This is at the server level as well as the database level, so if you only migrated the databases then you need to create a login for the AD group, and reattach orphaned users. You can use this DbaTools function https://docs.dbatools.io/Repair-DbaDbOrphanUser.html

Comment: Have you vetted the SQL Server Logs node in SSMS yet? If you look for login failure events (Error 18456) and take note of their `State` numbers you can compare them against those listed at [MSSQLSERVER_18456](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-18456-database-engine-error) to determine the problem.

Comment: Ok, we got this figured out.  The issue was a Group Policy that pointed the users to user a particular SQL server which in our case was the old SQL server.  If anyone is curious this is were we found that entry.  Group Policy Management Editor, User Configuration, Preferences, Regisery, Server.